# How do I crawl the websites that SimpleHTMLDom returns?

Tags: php, html, dom

I got Simple HTML Dom working, but now I want it to start crawling the url's it returns, without crawling url's that it has already crawled. How can I do that with PHP/MySQL/HTML?

```
<?php 
    include "/simple_html_dom.php";
    $target_url = "http://www.daparadise.com/";
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($target_url);
    foreach($html->find('a') as $link){
        echo $href->href."<br />";
    }
    $html -> clear();
?>
```

I have looked it up, but I can't seem to find anything about searching the results it returns.

Comment: Way too broad, SO is for specific programming questions.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to crawl the urls it returns. I've looked it up but i can't fiend anything. I'm trying to figure out how i can do so....

Answer (score 0):

Are you listing the images of a particular page? Your code does that. And its not crawling. For crawling you would typically look out for `<a>` tags, get the `src` attribute, push it to a stack or a queue, and crawl further.

---

The general idea:

- queue = array($curPage); //or use a Stack for Depth first search; you could run in circles (cycles)
- While queue is not empty: # or any better condition..

  - pop out first element. Get the URL of the page.
  - check if this page exists in the DB already; if so:

    - (continue with next iteration of while) //avoid cycles.
  - Use your DOM parser to parse out this page.
  - Grab any detail you want out of this page and store them to your DB
  - Look for all `<a>` tags. For each `<a>` tag do:

    - Get the `src` attribute
    - Push the `src` attribute to the queue.
  - (continue)

Comment: I didn't really figure out the main thing i was attempting. But i did enter all the information it got into the database. And i have it check to see if the url is already in the database, if not it will enter it. And everyday at 12AM and 12PM it will re-crawl and add more into the database.